# How to pass data form node js to Angular 1.x, if some one is hitting node js api?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, node-modules, angular1.6, nodejs-server

I am working on functionality where the user can hit 'test.com/sso' with post request. After validating the request, how can I send return value to Angular js 1.X?  I am using nodeJs as a backend.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs
-server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser =require('body-parse');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/angular')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/sso', function(req,res){
    //Something...(your code)
  .then(data =>{
    return res.status(200).json(data + "RESPONSE FROM SERVER");
  )}.catch(error=>{
    res.send(error);
  )}
)};

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server Listening On Port 3000"):
)};
```

Comment: are we returning value in our application, if other 3rd party hitting our API?

Comment: ya, to allow it only for specific domain use response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'domain.com');      you can also use 'npm vhost' package and for securing the app use 'npm helmet'.